# how can i fixe my given problem in MySQL code?

Tags: mysql

I'm learning MySQL and i had an activity (created a database of basic blog site) this blog site is for posting articles.
It was given that : 'It is possible to comment articles. If the commentator is a registered user, the comment is linked to his account. It is possible to comment an article without being connected, without even having an account.'
Any idea for that with MySQL code?

Answer (score 0):

This community does not help with school assignments. But I'll give you few hints, do research on them and figure out a solution.

- Database relations (Primary Keys vs Foreign Keys).
- Table's Column nullable feature.
- HTML anchor tags
- CRUD operations.

Start with simple CRUD operations when doing practical implementation.

Comment: Perhaps it shouldn't, but it definitely does!